# Github action SSH Execute Commands

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions, continuous-delivery

Is there any other github action besides appleboy/ssh-action, that not using Docker, for SSH Execute Commands

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be one, which means you would need to make a custom action yourself.

As illustrated in "[Custom GitHub Actions in Go Without Docker](https://www.steveyackey.com/post/gopherjs-github-actions/)" by [Steve Yackey](https://twitter.com/steveyackey), you can do so, [using Go](https://gist.github.com/andrielfn/7aa336f9b6dc9e2a5dac) to create an SSH connection and execute commands.
This is one example of such an approach.